# Does AssertionError ever get thrown by Java outside of using assert*

Tags: java, android, jvm, dalvik

I like to use `AssertionError` in my test code to alert me when things that shouldn't happen, happen. Recently I've been wondering if I could be silently swallowing arcane errors thrown by the JVM or Dalvik (or any other Android stock library) in weird failure modes.

Anyone know where (if at all) `AssertionError`s are thrown by *stock* code in the JVM or in Android (not 3rd party libraries)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many results found in a search of the frameworks project of Android Lollipop 5.0.1r1 (where most of the code a dev interacts with is) [androidxref](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/s?n=25&start=0&sort=relevancy&q=AssertionError&project=frameworks) that contain AssertionErrors being thrown.

For what it's worth, there isn't a ton of them in there and, from the few that I looked at, the likelihood of ever actually triggering them seems low but hey, it's possible.